# Design practice for REST API into existing .NET C# website

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, rest, post

I'd like to have our user landing web-server POST XML to our computation web server (to crunch over the XML data). The landing and computing web-servers are only connected via the internet - so it seems best to have a REST API on the computing web-server so the XML data can POSTed for processing.

To be honest, we're all SW engineers but our competency is in the algorithmic processing, not the web plumbing or ASP.NET itself. I looked around and saw WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) being kicked around quite a bit. I'm concerned WCF might be too complex/over engineered for our situation.

So, what is the simplest way for me to enable the existing web-forms based processing website to accept POSTed XML? I guess I need to register a URI (in web.config?) as the API interface, have a handler on that URI and retrieve the XML string - I just don't know the implementational steps :(. So a toy example or a pointer to a tutorial would be awesome!

BTW, once I have the XML string on the processing server, I'm golden!

Thanks
Sid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I read up several documents to be able to answer my own question. Basically WCF REST has been changing quite a bit. It's quite complicated in the setup in earlier versions but in recent versions (.NET 4 and WCF REST starter kit) the overhead of configuration is a lot less.

To get WCF REST running quickly, I basically did 3 things.

1. Setup the path to the service in global.asax.cs (I had to manually add/edit this as global.asax and global.asax.cs)
2. Setup the "service contract" (i.e. "doThisMethod" inside http://localhost/doThisMethod/ )
3. Setup the "data contract" (i.e. if you're POSTing any XML/JSON via the HTTP body, this "maps"/serializes between XML/JSON and the native C# objects.)

For very basic REST APIs (i.e. only HTTP GET) just the first two steps are sufficient. Please note, I scrubbed out some stuff during copy-pasting, but you should get the idea ...

**Step1a**

global.asax

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="~/App_Code/Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MyBLL.Global" Language="C#" %>
```

**Step1b**

global.asax.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;

public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("/", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(TestService)));
    }
}
```

**Step2a**

As you can see, I split the interface (abstract class) and the actual implementation into two separate files for clean separation.

TestInterface.cs

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

[ServiceContract]
interface TestInterface
{
    [OperationContract]
    string TestAsXML(string extra);

    [OperationContract]
    string TestAsJSON(string extra);
}
```

**Step2b**
TestService.cs

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class TestService : TestInterface

    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Test/{username}", Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    public string TestAsXML(string username)
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
        return String.Format("Hello {0}!", String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username) ? "world" : username);
    }

    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Test/{username}?format=json", Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public string TestAsJSON(string username)
    {
        // NOTE, if we GET this from a browsers, it will most likely have 
        // "Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*" in the HTTP header
        // So the framework will return XML instead. Try from Fiddler2 instead or
        // write your own WCF client or from AJAX
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json";
        return String.Format("Hello {0}!", String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username) ? "world" : username);
    }
```

**Step3**

For the "test" example above, everything is over the URI itself (due to GET), so you don't need the stuff below. Practically, once you want to use POST etc, you'll need to send the object in the HTTP body. When exchanging Data, use a "Data Contract" to leverage WCF's features as below.

Here I'll be sending one class in the HTTP body, which in turn has one string and one int within.

TestInput.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

// "" needed to clear out ugly xmlns namespace tags to make it plain old XML (POX)
// If you want them, ether take it out or specify on your own
[DataContract(Name = "TestInput", Namespace = "")] 
public class TestInput
{
    // NOTE: If Order property is skipped, the data will be serialized 
    // alphabetically per variable names!!
    // This can kill services, so better to be explicit
    [DataMember(Order = 0)] 
    int SomeNumber;

    // NOTE: If Name property is used XML will have UserName instead of internalUserName
    [DataMember(Name="UserName", Order = 1)] 
    string internalUserName;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you merely want the thinnest possible layer, without messing with the plumbing or figuring out wcf, create an asp.net web project then right click and add item choose an httphandler and in the event it gives pull the xml string from response.items[strings key]. post it as the url of the ashx?key=your xml string

Comment: 1) If I were to stuff the XML string (it's actually a large file) into the URL wouldn't that GET instead of POST? One reason for POST is because it's NOT idempotent for me ...

Comment: 2) I guess you mean the request object and not the response object to extract the XML string? If I were to send the XML string as a hidden form field, it looks like I can read it off as
`XMLstr = context.Request.Form[indexHiddenXMLField];`
BUT I suspect it's the wrong way to do so because the HTTP request would then look like 
`<..>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 31

HiddenXMLField=<xml here>`
I think the Content-Type should reflect XML (text/xml ?) and the body should be real XML. This is a hunch - I could be wrong as I've never designed a real RESTful API

Comment: 3) How can I eliminate the .ashx extension so server.com\API\incoming.ashx => server.com\API\incoming (or maybe \ at the end too) ? ..... I had to split that into 3 comments to fit. Sorry!

Comment: I was speaking strictly of the simplest immediate method without messing with anything. The right way to do this is with a WCF web service. Though in my method, to get your statefulness, just use static resources (be they files, databases, or a literal in memory static) and be concious of thread safety.

Comment: For the URL, you can simply through the IIS manager UI go to the properties of the folder and set incoming.ashx as your default document

Comment: If it's a very large file, I would maybe gzip and base64 it before putting it on the URL, and then in the ashx decompress it